# Combine accessor and mutator logic to add custom attributes to a model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I know about Laravel's [accessors and mutators](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) that can adjust attribute values when getting or setting a model. However, this can be done only with existing model attributes. I wonder if there's any way to create a combination of accessor and mutator that would let me set custom attributes for every model item.

Then, when I e.g. retrieve tags with Eloquent:

```
$tags = Tag::all();
```

I could access the **existing** attributes in a loop:

```
foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo $tag->id.'<br>';
    echo $tag->name.'<br>';
    // and ohers
}
```

but **also** the custom ones that I set, like `$tag->customAttr1`, `$tag->customAttr2`.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is example for adding custom attributes to your model.
$appends array will add those. While querying your table using eloquent, .. respective getters will be called to set the values.

In the following code snippet '**parent_name**' and '**parent_img_url**' are custom attributes and **getParentNameAttribute** and **getParentImgUrlAttribute** are getters.

One can modify the code of getters as per our need.

```
class Code extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'codes';
    protected $appends = array('parent_name', 'parent_img_url');

    protected $guarded = array();

    public static $rules = array();

    public function components()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Component', 'component_codes', 'component_id', 'code_id');
    }

    public function getParentNameAttribute()
    {
        $parent = Component::find(50);
        return $parent->name_en;
    }

    public function getParentImgUrlAttribute()
    {
        $parent = Component::find(50);
        return $parent->thumb;
    }

}
```

Comment: The `$appends` model property and custom accessors do the trick beautifully. Thanks a lot!